# How to import file directly from my users download folder into the server storage directory Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I want to push a button in my laravel application. That button should copy the excel file from the download folder and save it into symlink storage directory. What should I use then to grab a file from downlaods.

I'm new and I don't see a lot of good explanations of the process. I would be just as happy if someone just pointed me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: System download folder? what is that?

Comment: From the user's filesytem, or your server's filesytem?

Comment: @WesleySmith Copy .csv file from my document to the server public folder

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur User folder like my document, download folder

Comment: It is not possible to automatically upload a file from the user's filesytem for security reasons. The user must interact with a file picker and manually select the file, there is no other way.